# Spark SQL - how to add two column value

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I add one or more columns in spark-sql?

in oracle, we are doing

```
select name, (mark1+mark2+mark3) as total from student
```

I'm looking for the same operation in spark-sql.

Comment: This should work fine in Spark. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it `withColumn` function.
If columns are numeric you can add them directly

```py
df.withColumn('total', 'mark1'+'mark2'+'mark3')
```

if columns are `string` and want to `concat` them

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn('total', F.concat('mark1','mark2','mark3'))
```

Comment: Your `concat` is correct but, for `df.withColumn('total', 'mark1'+'mark2'+'mark3')` how does spark know `mark1` is a column? (you should either use  `df.mark1` or `from pyspark.sql.functions import col col('mark1') + col('mark2') + col('mark3')`. Right?

Answer (score 3):

If you register dataframe as a temporary table (for example, via `createOrReplaceTempView()`) then the exact same SQL statement that you specified will work.

If you are using DataFrame API instead, the [Column class](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) defines various operators, including addition. In code, it would look something like this:

```
val df = Seq( (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) ).toDF("c1", "c2")
df.withColumn( "c3", $"c1" + $"c2" ).show
```